# What does the dice roll affect when travelling?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

When travelling to another location via map screen what does the dice roll affect?

[image: Map screen showing dice roll of 9]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dice roll while travelling affects your chances of being randomly attacked by mobs during your travels. high rolls = higher chances of safe travel.

Answer (score 1):

Do not think so exactly. I am thinking that if you roll below the intervall you will get definietly attacked, if you roll above that you will survive without an attack.

In the case of the picture the hero will be definietly attacked by mobs, because he rolled 9 and the intervall start from 10.

Comment: Pretty sure this is correct, from what I remember - it's a binary 'you will/will not get attacked'

Comment: Not clear how this differs from the accepted answer besides describing the picture.

Comment: It's describing a bit more explicitly the feature so can be understood more easily. As well it saying exactly what will happen after a dice roll, and not talking only about probabilities because its binary as Alex said. So it can be helpful for some users, for others they may understand this game feature perfectly.